# Deserialize json file to c# list<object> but the properies won't come into the object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to get data from a json file to a project object that I have made that looks like this:

```
public class Project
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Client_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public bool billable  { get; set; }
    public string bill_by { get; set; }
}
```

The json file that I want to deserialize has over 30 properties in each object. I have only included a few in the object I have made above. That might be the problem I don't know?

When I do this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Project> projectsList = ser.Deserialize<List<Project>>(jsonString);
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "project": {
      "id": 10060601,
      "client_id": 4233570,
      "name": "arsnealWebsite",
      "code": "",
      "active": true,
      "billable": true,
      "bill_by": "none",
      "hourly_rate": null,
      "budget": null,
      "budget_by": "none",
      "notify_when_over_budget": false,
      "over_budget_notification_percentage": 80,
      "over_budget_notified_at": null,
      "show_budget_to_all": false,
      "created_at": "2016-02-17T18:59:22Z",
      "updated_at": "2016-02-17T19:20:27Z",
      "starts_on": "2016-02-19",
      "ends_on": "2016-02-29",
      "estimate": null,
      "estimate_by": "none",
      "hint_earliest_record_at": "2016-02-17",
      "hint_latest_record_at": "2016-02-17",
      "notes": "",
      "cost_budget": null,
      "cost_budget_include_expenses": false
    }
  }
]
```

... the list gets created with the exact amount of objects that the json file have but the properties in the json file doesn't come into the properties of my project object I have created? the name of the properties in the json file and the name of the properties in the c# code(the class above) are exactly the same? How come the properties value doesn't go into the properties value of the project object?

Comment: And the jsonString value looks like ... ?

Comment: And did you try to de-serialize a single object?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's much easier to help you when we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Robert Haile, please post a sample of the JSON data. If it contains sensitive information, clean that out first of course. It is difficult to help unless you provide this information.

Comment: the jsonstring is pretty long scroll down and check it out @OndrejSvejdar

Comment: when i try Deserialize a single object(Project pro = ser.Deserialize<Project>(jsonString);) it dosent work i get a message when i try Deserialize a single object(Project pro = ser.Deserialize<Project>(jsonString);) it dosent work i get a error message The type ApiTest.Models.Project not supported for deserialization of a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the `"project"` json property.
Create wrapper class around `Project` property like:

```
public class ProjectWrapper
{  
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}


var projectsList = ser.Deserialize<List<ProjectWrapper>>(jsonString)
  .Select(p => p.Project).ToList();
```

Comment: dont quite get why i have to create a projectwrapper doe. could you explain that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [DataContractjsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) and data annotation inside your object.

So your object need to be:

```
[DataContract]
public class Project
    {  
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="ClientId")]        
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]        
        public string code { get; set; }
        [DataMember]        
        public bool active { get; set; }
        [DataMember]        
        public bool billable  { get; set; }
        [DataMember]        
        public string bill_by { get; set; }
    }
```

and below one example of serialization:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Project>));
    
string result = string.Empty;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   try
   {
      serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
      ms.Position = 0;
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
      {
         result = sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // your exception handling
   }
}
```

Note: you can change output property name by data annotation like example above (ClientId)

Bye